# null value in column "user_id" of relation "core_bedroomsummary" violates not-null constraint | DETAIL: Failing row contains (2, title, string, null)

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I feel like this should be so easy to resolve but i cant seem to figure out why its not pulling the specific users uuid. The whole point is for the user to be able to have their own comments.

views.py

```
class BedroomSummaryViewSet(mixins.DestroyModelMixin,
                            mixins.UpdateModelMixin,
                            mixins.ListModelMixin,
                            mixins.CreateModelMixin,
                            viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    """Manage comments in the database."""
    serializer_class = serializers.BedroomSummarySerializer
    queryset = BedroomSummary.objects.all()
    authentication_classes = [TokenAuthentication]
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    def get_queryset(self):
        """Filter queryset to authenticated user."""
        return self.queryset.filter(user=self.request.user).order_by('-title')
```

serializers.py

```
class BedroomSummarySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """Serializer for interior summary."""

    class Meta:
        model = BedroomSummary
        fields = ['id', 'title', 'comment']
        read_only_field = ['id']
```

models.py

```
class BedroomSummary(models.Model):
    """Bedroom Summary Model"""
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    title = models.CharField(max_length=55)
    comment = models.CharField(max_length=2000)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to inject the `user` in the item you create, so:

```
from rest_framework.viewsets import ModelViewSet


class BedroomSummaryViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    # …

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(user=self.request.user)
```

Comment: sigh i knew it was going to be something easy like that haha thank you